# Proving certain límit exists.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm proving the next exercise and I'm so close to conclude but I don't know what can I do.

> Let $(\varphi_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of non-negative functions in $C([0,1])$ such that for all $k\in\omega$ the next limit exist $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}t^{k}\varphi_{n}(t)\, dt$$Prove that for all $f\in C([0,1])$ the next limit exist $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f(t)\varphi_n(t)\, dt$$

Let $k=0$. By hypothesis $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\varphi_n(t)\,dt$$exist. Moreover, if $p(t)$ is a polynomial then $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}p(t)\varphi_n(t)\,dt $$because $p(t)=a_0+a_1t+\cdots+a_mt^{m}$ and then $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}p(t)\varphi_n(t)\,dt=a_0\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1} \varphi_n(t)+\cdots+a_m\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} t^{m}\varphi_n(t)\,dt$$Let $f\in C[0,1]$. We can take $(p_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of polynomials such that converges uniformly to $f$. Since $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\varphi_n(t)\,dt$$then there exist $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n,m\geq N$  $$\left| \int_{0}^{1}\varphi_n(t)\, dt-\int_{0}^{1}\varphi_m(t)\, dt\right|=\left|\int_{0}^{1}\varphi_n(t)-\varphi_m(t)\, dt \right|<\text{apropiate $\varepsilon$}$$ If $n,n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n,m\geq N$ then $$\left| \int_{0}^{1} f(t)\varphi_n(t)\, dx-\int_{0}^{1} f(t)\varphi_m(t)\, dt\right|=\left|\int_{0}^{1} f(t)(\varphi_n(t)-\varphi_m(t)) \, dt\right|$$Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sup\{|f(t)-p_k(t)\mid t\in[0,1]\}<\text{another apropiate $\varepsilon$}$. Then $$\left|\int_{0}^{1} f(t)(\varphi_n(t)-\varphi_m(t)) \, dt\right|=\left|\int_{0}^{1} (f(t)-p_k(t)+p_k(t))(\varphi_n(t)-\varphi_m(t)) \, dt\right|$$This is the same as $$\left|\int_{0}^{1} (f(t)-p_k(t))(\varphi_n(t)-\varphi_m(t))+p_k(t)(\varphi_n(t)-\varphi_m(t))\, dt \right|\leq$$ $$\leq\int_{0}^{1}\left| (f(t)-p_k(t))(\varphi_n(t)-\varphi_m(t))+p_k(t)(\varphi_n(t)-\varphi_m(t))\right|\, dt$$ $$\leq\int_{0}^{1} \left| (f(t)-p_k(t))(\varphi_n(t)-\varphi_m(t))\right|\, dt+\int_{0}^{1}\left|p_k(t)(\varphi_n(t)-\varphi_m(t))\right| \, dt$$But from here I don't know how to conclude. It's not easy because I can bound the absolute value of integrals but not the integral of absolute value. In summary, my idea is aproximate $f$ by polinomials and use the fact that for polynomials the limit exist. Also I found the same question here [Existence of Limit :](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36870/existence-of-limit) but the answer is so short and I can't see really how to conclude from there.

Comment: what isn't clear from the that answer?

Comment: I understand that $p_k\phi_n$ converges uniformly to $f\phi_n$ as $k\to\infty$. But, I don't know how to work with the "double" limit. The limit inside the integral and the out limit.  I want to prove directly that $\int_{0}^{1} f(t)\varphi_n(t)\, dt$ is a Cauchy sequence. This makes me understand better the proof. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{array}
\left|| \int_0^1(f(t) - p_k(t))(\phi_n(t) - \phi_m(t)) + p_k(t) (\phi_n(t) - \phi_m(t)) dt || \\
= || \int_0^1(f(t) - p_k(t))(\phi_n(t) - \phi_m(t)) dt + \int_0^1 p_k(t) (\phi_n(t) - \phi_m(t)) dt || \\
\leq || \int_0^1 (f(t) - p_k(t))(\phi_n(t) - \phi_m(t)) dt || + ||\int_0^1  p_k(t) (\phi_n(t) - \phi_m(t)) dt || \\
\leq \int_0^1 || (f(t) - p_k(t))(\phi_n(t) - \phi_m(t)) || dt + ||\int_0^1  p_k(t) (\phi_n(t) - \phi_m(t)) dt || \\
\leq \int_0^1 || \varepsilon_2 (\phi_n(t) - \phi_m(t)) || dt + || \int_0^1  p_k(t) (\phi_n(t) - \phi_m(t)) dt ||
\end{array}
and working with the second integral.

In other ways: First, split up the integral and only then use the monotony.

Please excuse the terrible typesetting, \left and \right do not react as I wish them to do.

Comment: Try `\left\|` and `\right\|` instead of `\left||` and `\right||`.

Comment: Feel invited to edit my answer. Following your comment, I have experimented a lot, but was not able to get a well-looking result which does not throw an error.

Comment: But I can't bound $K=\int_{0}^{1} ||\varepsilon_2 (\phi_n(t)-\phi_m(t))|| dt$. I only can bound $\left| \int_{0}^{1} \phi_n(t)-\phi_m(t)\right|\leq K$. What can I do?